# How to I add an icon to my c++ executable using Gradle?

Tags: c++, windows, gradle, icons, mingw

I want to add an icon to my cpp executable (.exe). I can't seem to find anything regarding it. I'm using the cpp plugin in Gradle. I have a folder in the project directory called etc with an icon in it. 
I have seen posts how to do it in visual studio or eclipse but I want to do it in Gradle so when I build, the executable with already have the icon.

My code:

```
apply plugin: 'cpp'

model { 
    components {
        main(NativeExecutableSpec) {
            sources {
                cpp {
                    source {
                        srcDirs "${projectDir}\\source"
                        include "**\\*.cpp" 
                    }

                    exportedHeaders {
                        srcDirs "${projectDir}\\source"
                        include "**\\*.h"
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    platforms {
        windows_x86 {
            operatingSystem "windows"
            architecture "x86"
        }
    }

    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            def libDir = "${projectDir}\\lib\\"

            ms {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file(libDir + "ms.dll")
                    sharedLibraryLinkFile = file(libDir + "ms.lib")
                }
            }

            conf {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file(libDir + "conf.dll")
                    sharedLibraryLinkFile = file(libDir + "conf.lib")
                }
            }

            supp {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file(libDir + "supp.dll")
                    sharedLibraryLinkFile = file(libDir + "supp.lib")
                }
            }
        }

    }

    toolChains {
        mingw_x86(Gcc) {
            path "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
            eachPlatform() {
                cCompiler.executable "gcc"
                cppCompiler.executable "g++"
                linker.executable "g++"
                assembler.executable "as"
                staticLibArchiver.executable "ar"
            }
            target("windows_x86")
        }
    }

    binaries {
        withType(NativeExecutableBinarySpec) {
            if (toolChain in Gcc) {
                cppCompiler.args "-m32"
                cppCompiler.args "-c"
                cppCompiler.args "-w"
                cppCompiler.args "-I${projectDir}\\include"
                cppCompiler.args "-std=c++11"
                cppCompiler.args "-MMD"
                cppCompiler.args "-MP"

                linker.args "-Llib"
                lib library: "ms", linkage: "shared"
                lib library: "conf", linkage: "shared"
                lib library: "supp", linkage: "shared"
            }
        }
    }
}
```